# How can I add brackets to my php string variable using cancatinating?

Tags: php, html

I'm using PHP version 5.5.12. Why is my browser putting a `<br />` when I am concatinating strings?

Let's say I want to add brackets to a variable to make it into an array variable like this:

```
$strName = $plyrMtchResult.'[]';
echo $strName;
```

Assuming `$plyrMtchResult` is `"Hello World"`, my browser show this when I view the page via view page source:

```
'Hello World' <br />'.'[]'
```

What I would like to see is: `$strName[]` in my page source. How can I add brackets to my variable using concatinating?

Thanks for helping..

Comment: What is the code before the `$strName = $plyrMtchResult.'[]';`?

Comment: The code before is a foreach ($playerMatchResult as $plyrMtchResult) {
           $strName=$plyrMtchResult;....... }

Comment: `var_dump($plyrMtchResult);`

Comment: Tell please what browser you use?

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you are trying to do

```
$withbrackets = '[' . $strName . ']';
```

Comment: I want the outcome to be $withbrackets[].  Your solution still contains a <br/> tag.

Comment: Working with Jacob's idea I did this:   $strName=$plyrMtchResult.'['.']'...but the browser still puts a <br/>tag between the word and the bracket.

Comment: Are there a br in `$plyrMtchResult`?

Comment: Got it...I use :  $strName=$plyrMtchResult.'['.']';
           $strName=preg_replace( "' <br />'", "", $strName );
           echo $strName;

Answer (score 0):

I used:
$strName=$plyrMtchResult.'['.']';
$strName=preg_replace( "' 
'", "", $strName );
echo $strName;

Answer (score 0):

Got it...I use :

```
$strName=$plyrMtchResult.'['.']'; 
$strName=preg_replace( "' <br />'", "", $strName ); 
echo $strName;
```